# sqlite query do simple calculations on result of subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have this query which I need to do on sqlite (iOS).

```
SELECT k.ZKUNDENNR, k.ZNAME1,
(SELECT SUM(vk.ZNETTO) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2013 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) AS summeJ,
(SELECT SUM(vk.ZNETTO) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2012 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeVJ,
(SELECT SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2012 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeDBVJ,
(SELECT SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2013 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeDBJ, 
((summeJ-summeVJ)/summeVJ*100) AS variance FROM ZKUNDE k WHERE summeJ>0 ORDER BY summeJ DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

What I need to do is to calculate the variance between `summeJ` and `summeVJ`, but I'm always getting this error: "no such column: summeJ". Can anyone help me please? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a subquery, because a column alias cannot be re-used at the same level of `select`:

```
SELECT t.*, ((summeJ-summeVJ)/summeVJ*100) AS variance
FROM (SELECT k.ZKUNDENNR, k.ZNAME1,
             (SELECT SUM(vk.ZNETTO) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2013 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) AS summeJ,
             (SELECT SUM(vk.ZNETTO) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2012 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeVJ,
             (SELECT SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2012 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeDBVJ,
             (SELECT SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2013 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeDBJ
      FROM ZKUNDE k
     ) t
WHERE summeJ>0
ORDER BY summeJ DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```